# How many types of Locks are there in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I was asked in an interview that how many types of locks are there in java, I knew about Synchronized(this) or synchronized method, and Reentrant Lock. Are there any other kind of locks I can acquire on an Object?

Comment: this might help you http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html

Comment: OT: I really wonder sometimes what interviewers are thinking ... as if someone would **count** this stuff.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about the job you're interviewing for, but if *I* asked you that question in an interview, then I would not be looking for a right answer.  I'd be trying to start a discussion where you tell me what locking means, how it works, how you use it, what kind of mistakes you or your peers have made with it, and what you learned from your/their mistakes.

I'd be looking to find out whether you understand the differences between locking that's provided by the language vs. locking that is provided by the libraries, vs. locking that's provided by the underlying hardware.

There is no job on Earth that you're disqualified from doing if you don't know exactly how many different kinds of lock are in the Java language, but there are lots of jobs that you shouldn't be doing if you don't know how to *talk* about it.

Comment: actually I didn't had much knowledge on Thread, so I thought that the no of locks should have a definite count. But posting question here I got my doubt clear.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by others there are several ways to synchronize code.

As far as I know, there are basically three different synchronization features in Java:

- Monitor-Objects (used with synchronize keyword)
- [Locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) (e.g. ReentrantLock)
- [Semaphores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (Quite similar to Locks, but they provide a pool of permits which can be claimed to enter a critical section; a Semaphore with a single available Token works equivalent to a Lock)

Comment: should Mutex be included in types of locks?

Comment: In Java there is no explicit `Mutex`. A mutex-like-behaviour can nevertheless be implemented by using any of the mentioned synchronization variants.

Comment: You say a `Semaphore` is a kind of lock.  Does that mean a `BlockingQueue` also is a kind of lock?  You could use a blocking queue anywhere that you would use a semaphore, but you can also use queues for other things that go beyond what semaphores can do.  Likewise, you could use a semaphore anywhere that you would use a non-reentrant `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` implementation, but you can also use the semaphore for other things that go beyond what a mere lock can do.

Comment: I see your point. As I understood the initial question, it was basically asked for the ways in which a lock on a certain section can be obtained. I would say, that also a BlockingQueue can therefore be seen as a kind of Lock. I know that Semaphor as well as the Queue can also serve other use cases than a "simple" lock can do and are not a lock as such. Nevertheless I think yes, they are also a kind of lock.

Answer (score 1):

From javadoc of [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) those are the implemented classes:

- `ReentrantLock`
- `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock`
- `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`

---

[`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html):

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended capabilities.

---

[`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) (from wich you can obtain a reference to `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock` and `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`):

> An implementation of ReadWriteLock supporting similar semantics to ReentrantLock.

Comment: I suspect the interviewer could also have taken into account Monitors, synchronize keyword, Mutex ...

Comment: Should mutex and semaphore should also be counted as locks?

Comment: So can we consider locks as general Lock(java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock), Syncronized, and  ReentrantLock (implements lock)?

Comment: @Sumitsagar Depends. If the interviewer specifically had `Lock`s (like the interface) in mind - then no. But human language can be deceiving. Maybe he also referred to other synchronization methods. In this case - yes. I honestly cannot tell because I wasn't there. If I had been the interviewee this would definitely be a question where I would request clarification.

Comment: @Sumitsagar no, if he asked specifically for Lock this is the answer. If he asked for any kind of mechanism to synchronize threads you can also add: low level synchronization (synchronized, wait, notify...), Semaphore, CyclicBarrier, CountDownLatch (and generally see the package java.util.concurrent)